# C++ Central Logging system

Tags: c++, logging, centralized

I've been asked to implement Centralized Logging system in C++. But I'm new to programming, and it doesn't really make sense, what needs to be done in class `Log`? I'm told that this class has to have 3 levels: ALL, ERROR, NONE. What should be in this levels? How should I link this class to my other source codes?

I still do not have clear view on Logging, and cant seem to find resources online. One of the task was not to spam `cout`. I am really struggling on this, if someone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Edit: Thank for answering. That helped, because I was not in 1st year and they taught python last year and i haven't, so that's why i am struggling with logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module of Python will give you a good idea of what a logging system should do. See `logging.DEBUG`, `logging.WARNING`, `logging.ERROR`, etc. for what 'levels' means. As for compiling and linking your class, that's a totally different issue altogether.

Other than that, not much for you. This is obviously homework, and you've shown little/no effort in terms of what you may have researched, or code you may have written.